# How to update listview item color and font dynamically?

Tags: c#, uwp

I would like to dynamically update my listview, I'll explain the situation: I have a MainPage in which I have declared in my xaml:

```
<controls:DockPanel Width="100" Height="100">
  <Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="myList" Width="100" Margin="10,0,0,'" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Item}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,-6" />
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</controls:DockPanel>
```

To which I have associated a view model

```
namespace My_app.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModel
    {
      private ObservableCollection<string> _items;
      private string _sItems;

      public MainPageViewModel()
      {
          _items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
      }

      public ObservableCollection<string> Items
      {
          get { return _items; }
          set
          {
              _items = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("Items");
          }
      }
}
```

So I have component that is displayed on the main page, that has a button to which I add a list and I would like to dynamically change the colors and font of this listview

```
private ViewModels.MainPageViewModel _viewModels;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       List<string> myList = new List<string>(somevalue);

       foreach (var x in myList)
       {
           view_.Pins.Add(x);
       }

       //after I want to dynamically change color and font of my items
}
```

What I would like to do then is to list the elements of the listview and change their color dynamically, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Items.Count; i++)
{
    //getItem(i)
    //change item color
    //change item font
}
```

Comment: How do you want to decide the color? Based on the string value? Or something else? Please share an example about what kind of behavior do you want to get.

Comment: From string value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [ValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter?view=winrt-22000) and Data Binding to achieve what you want.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a **ValueConverter** for based on your requirement. You need to set the background color and the font color based on the value string. So you need to have a parameter to indicate if when to set the background color and the font color.
2. You need to create a **data template** for the ListView item so that the item could use Data Binding.

The code for the value converter:

```
 public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter 
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {

        SolidColorBrush brush = null;
        // Retrieve the parameter string and data string.
        string formatString = parameter as string;
        string data = value as string;
        // retrun different brush based on the parameter and data string
        if (formatString.Equals("foreground"))
        {
            switch (data) 
            {
                case "1":
                    brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    break;
            }
               
        }
        else if (formatString.Equals("background"))
        {
            switch (data)
            {
                case "1":
                    brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.AliceBlue);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return brush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The code in the Xaml:

```
   <ListView x:Name="myList" Width="100" Margin="10,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,-6" />
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid Width="200" Height="50" Background="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter},ConverterParameter=background}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="{Binding Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter},ConverterParameter=foreground}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

How it looks like:

[image]

This is a simple implementation for this. You could change the data template and the logic of the ValeConverter based on your own scenario.

Comment: Thank you! This is the result I would like to get, I only have an implementation problem as I do after inserting the elements so in the same way I have the never list of elements:
`
1
1
1
1
`
Elements that all have the same color, how do I review it and change the color dynamically, how should the logic of my viewmodel be? or how should i be able to get the iesiemo object and change its color? i.e. I can how can I implement this logic:

Comment: `
for (int i = 0; i <item counts; i ++) {
// getItem I change color and background via my viewmodel


}
`

I have read the docs but I am not sure how to do this

Comment: The logic is in the `ColorConverter`, you don't need to review it. The converter will change the color based on the value via binding. What you need is to go your own logic in the converter